# using re-search-forward in yas-snippet

Tags: regular-expressions, yasnippet, search

I'm trying to develop a new yas-snippet for expanding a common c++ log function I use a lot. The first parameter to the LOG function can be guessed by searching for existing LOG calls in the buffer. For example, if the user 
types

```
LOG(QWERTY_ID, EVENT, DEBUG, "wooo!");
LOG<TAB>
```

I would like yas-snippet to expand to

```
LOG(QUERY_ID, UNKNOWN_EVENT, , "");
```

If the LOG function hasn't been used before then I would like to expand to:

```
LOG(<SUBSYSTEM_ID>, UNKNOWN_EVENT, , "");
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The SUBSYSTEM_ID part isn't working for me. This is what I have so far

```
LOG(${1:`(progn
(beginning-of-buffer)
(re-search-forward "LOG(\s*\\([A-Za-z_]+\\)\s*," (point-max) t)
(let ((m (match-string-no-properties 1)))
  (if m m ("<SUBSYSTEM_ID>"))))`}, ${2:UNKNOWN_EVENT}, ${3:$$(yas-choose-value '("DEBUG" "INFO" "WARN" "ERROR" "FATAL" "OFF"))}, ${4:""}$0);
```

It actually just expands to some text that it seems to have matched from within the snippet itself.

Comment: https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/141#issuecomment-2625455